# PHP multidimensional array output HTML table

Tags: php, foreach

I have inside one array two arrays with keys and I want to output this in HTML table by year date. For example:

```
Jaar | Basis         | Secundair
2021 | Wiskunde      | PAV 3de graad b-stroom
2021 | --------------| Burgerzin 3de graad b-stroom
2020 | Informatieverwerving en -verwerking met ICT | Kritisch denken & mediawijsheid
```

My code:

```
$output = "<table class='noborder homepeilingskalender fixed_header'><thead><tr><th>".get_field('titel_eerste_kolom')."</th><th>".get_field('titel_tweede_kolom')."</th><th>".get_field('titel_derde_kolom')."</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

              foreach ($combined as $ar) {
                      $mark = 0;
                        echo '<pre>' , var_dump($ar), '</pre>';
                    //  echo '<pre>' , var_dump($ar), '</pre>';
                   foreach ($ar[0] as $fkey => $fval) {

                       foreach($ar[1] as $skey => $sval){           
            $fval['basis'] = !$mark ? $fval['basis'] : '';
             echo '<pre>' , var_dump($ar[0]), '</pre>';
            $term_slug_ba = get_term_by('slug',$fval["basis"],'leer_vakgebied'); 
            $name_slug = $term_slug_ba->slug;

            $term_slug_so = get_term_by('slug',$sval["sec"],'leer_vakgebied_so'); 
            $name_slug_so = $term_slug_so->slug;

            $output .= "<tr><td>".$fval['jaar']."</td><td>";

            /* basisonderwijs peilingen met link */
             if(!empty($name_slug))
            {
            if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == "en") {
            //show English
            $output .= "<a href='".esc_url( add_query_arg( 'peiling', $name_slug,site_url( '/knowledge-sharing/polls/primary') ))."'>".$fval['basis']. "</a></td>";
            } elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == "fr") {
            //show french
            $output .= "<a href='".esc_url( add_query_arg( 'peiling', $name_slug,site_url( '/partage-des-connaissances/sondages/primaire') ))."'>".$fval['basis']. "</a></td>";
            } else {
            //show default language
            $output .= "<a href='".esc_url( add_query_arg( 'peiling', $name_slug,site_url( '/kennisdeling/peilingen/basisonderwijs') ))."'>".$fval['basis']. "</a></td>";
            }
            }

            /* secundair onderijs peilingen met link */
             if(!empty($name_slug_so))
            {
            if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == "en") {
            //show English
            $output .= "<td><a href='".esc_url( add_query_arg( 'peiling', $name_slug_so,site_url( '/knowledge-sharing/polls/secondary-education') ))."'>".$sval['sec']." | ". $sval["onderwijsniveau"]."</a></td>";
            } elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == "fr") {
            //show French
            $output .= "<td><a href='".esc_url( add_query_arg( 'peiling', $name_slug_so,site_url( '/partage-des-connaissances/sondages/enseignement-secondaire') ))."'>".$sval['sec']." | ". $sval["onderwijsniveau"]."</a></td>";
            } else {
            //show the default language
            $output .= "<td><a href='".esc_url( add_query_arg( 'peiling', $name_slug_so,site_url( '/kennisdeling/peilingen/secundair-onderwijs') ))."'>".$sval['sec']." | ". $sval["onderwijsniveau"]."</a></td>";
            }
            }

            $output .="</tr>";
            if ($fval['basis']) $mark = 1;

}

              }
              }
$output .= "</table>";
```

See on other question: [Building of HTML table with two multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59336166/building-of-html-table-with-two-multidimensional-arrays/)

But i have only one problem that the array index 0 can be empty and array index 1 also. For example like this:

````
   array(2) {
 [0]=>
 array(1) {
   [0]=>
   array(2) {
     ["jaar"]=>
     string(4) "2005"
     ["basis"]=>
     string(26) "Wereldoriëntatie (natuur)"
   }
 }
 [1]=>
 NULL
}
array(2) {
 [0]=>
 array(1) {
   [0]=>
   array(2) {
     ["jaar"]=>
     string(4) "2002"
     ["basis"]=>
     string(8) "Wiskunde"
   }
 }
 [1]=>
 NULL
}
array(2) {
 [0]=>
 array(1) {
   [0]=>
   array(2) {
     ["jaar"]=>
     string(4) "2001"
     ["basis"]=>
     string(10) "Nederlands"
   }
 }
 [1]=>
 NULL
} ```
For now the second foreach stops if array index 1 is empty? How can i continue the foreach until all the values from index 0 and 1 Thanks!
````

Answer (score 0):

If your index 0 or 1 is empty it is not an `array` anymore, so it cannot do a `foreach` on an empty result and will result in an error.
You should put some `if` statements around your foreach to check if the key exists before looping trough it

```
if(array_key_exists(0, $ar)){
  // then do foreach
}
else{
  // key doesn't exists but loop continues
}
```

Do this for index 0 and for index 1.

Comment: I don't know what you exactly mean... how can i do this if one array is empty that foreach still keep the values from the non empty array. i try this with your if statement outside the foreach and inside the foreach but no changing.